# Scheduling Cron Job for a Specific Hour Range in a Week

Tags: 14.04, server, bash, cron

I'm looking to run a cron job for specific hours in a week. The reason I'm doing this is due to the timezone being pegged exactly 7 hours ahead of New York time irrespective of daylight savings (this is a non-standard timezone as far as I'm aware).

The execution times in this "timezone" are simply every hour in the day from Monday to Friday, and thus, the cron job *would* be simple. However, as this is a non-standard timezone it's not that simple but I have a fix for it with the below:

```
0  17-23 * * 0-4 /path/to/script
0  0-16  * * 1-5 /path/to/script
```

The first job runs from 17h00-23h00, Sunday to Thursday (00h00-06h00, Monday to Friday in my timezone), and the second job running from 00h00-16h00, Monday to Friday (07h00-23h00, Monday to Friday in my timezone).

So my question is how would I be able to consolodate these two lines into a single one. Obviously, this is just academic at this point as the two lines seem to do the job perfectly fine.

Also, I'm currently using Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: It's a good question, but I don't think you can.  Maybe someone else might know.  As far as putting things together, they are separated by commas.  So, the time would work as `0 0-16,17-23 * *` but the days of the week would be where it messes up.  It might try to run them all `0-5` or Sunday thru Friday.  If your scripts are different, it might no be able to run two separate commands on one line knowing which days / times each one is supposed to run on.  I hope that I am wrong though.